# How to group two lines into one line and sum the amount when use union

Tags: sql-server-2005

I used union in my SQL script and get the data below, my question is how can i group line 3 and line 4 become line 0 and to sum up the amount for line 3 and 4. Thanks in advance!!

From:
        Document       Line     Amount

```
    11000003    1   20.6    
    11000003    2   55  

    11000003    3   55  
    11000003    4   20.6
```

---

To:
        Document       Line     Amount

```
    11000003    1   20.6    
    11000003    2   55  

    11000003    0   75.6
```

Here is my script:

```
Select Document, Row_number () Over (Partition by DocumentNumber Order by DocumentNumber as Line, Amount
From Table A 

Union 

Select Document, Row_number () Over (Partition by DocumentNumber Order by DocumentNumber as Line, Amount
from Table A
```

but i want to edit the union result to fit my requirement which is to group it to one line only and sum up the amount

Comment: Show us some SQL. We can answer generally but it may not help you...

Comment: By which criterion should lines 3 and 4 be grouped?

Comment: Are they always lines 3 & 4, the other lines 1 & 2? We can't see your query, so anything we provide at the moment will be a guess.

Comment: I've marked up the code you've supplied, but it's obviously *not* your real code, since your `ROW_NUMBER()` functions are incomplete. We are *trying* to understand your problem, but if you post broken code, don't give good sample data, etc, then we're limited in what we can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT Document, SUM(Line), SUM(Amount)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Document
```

Comment: That would yield a single result row, and I don't know where you get SUM(Line) from.

Comment: Actually the line is generated by Row_number, i can't select it

Comment: Here is my script: Select Document, Row_number () Over (Partition by DocumentNumber Order by DocumentNumber as Line, Amount from Table A Union Select Document, Row_number () Over (Partition by DocumentNumber Order by DocumentNumber as Line, Amount from Table A also, but i want to edit the union result to fit my requirement which is to group it to one line only and sum up the amount

Answer (score 0):

One example that literally only works with your supplied data would be:

```
SELECT Document,Line,Sum(Amount)
FROM
   (SELECT Document,CASE Line WHEN 3 THEN 0 WHEN 4 THEN 0 ELSE Line END as Line,Amount
   FROM
      (<Your current query>) t
   ) t
GROUP BY Document,Line
```

But I've no way of knowing if that fits with your wider needs, since you haven't given much of a specification yet.

Comment: @user1111569 - edit your question, and add your script there. Don't try and post it in a comment (you won't be able to format it well as code (but you should format it when editing your question))

Comment: Here is my script: Select Document, Row_number () Over (Partition by DocumentNumber Order by DocumentNumber as Line, Amount from Table A        Union Select Document, Row_number () Over (Partition by DocumentNumber Order by DocumentNumber as Line, Amount from Table A also, but i want to edit the union result to fit my requirement which is to group it to one line only and sum up the amount

Comment: @user1111569 - As I predicted, the code is unreadable here in the comments (among other things, it seems to be incomplete, containing more opening parentheses(`(`) than closing ones). Please edit your question, add your script in there, use the code formatting facility (`{}` button), and check that the preview looks correct.